# How do I distribute a program created with Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have created a program with VC++ by the first time, and when I send the .exe file to other people they can't open it. It doesn't crash because of an error, it simply doesn't open. What do I have to do if I want other people to correctly use my program?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of VS? Did you compile it in Release mode? Also, the [VS redistributable package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en) needs to be installed on computers that don't already have VS in order for the program to run

Comment: I'm using VS 2010. I didn't know I had to compile it in Release mode. What diferences are between Debug mode and Release mode?

Comment: You might also want to look into creating an installer for your application - visual studio is able to do this as long as your requirements aren't too complicated. You'll want to create a visual studio deployment project in your solution.

Comment: Thank you everyone, now everybody can use my program.

Comment: I'm not sure compiling in Release is required, but it certainly can't hurt, and Debug builds are not really meant to be distributed (and are also generally slower).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to bundle your application with vcredist_x86.exe found on this page:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84

Answer (score 2):

You can customize that but generally Debug builds include information for the debugger to work well and use different run time libraries that may not be installed on your target system. Release builds are using optimizations during compile and link times, do not include debugging info and are linked with binaries that are included in MS redistributable package.